# Assembly showing a lot of repeating code?

Tags: c++, assembly, gdb, x86-64, disassembly

So I'm working on some binary to assembly to c++ code. It's for a project.

When I disassemble the binary I'm getting a lot of repeating assembly code and I'm not sure what it's doing. It's almost like it's just pointing it's way down.

```
   0x0000000000000000 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000000001 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000000004 <+4>:     lea    0x0(%rip),%rsi        # 0xb <main+11>
   0x000000000000000b <+11>:    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 0x12 <main+18>
   0x0000000000000012 <+18>:    callq  0x17 <main+23>
   0x0000000000000017 <+23>:    callq  0x1c <main+28>
   0x000000000000001c <+28>:    mov    %eax,0x0(%rip)        # 0x22 <main+34>
   0x0000000000000022 <+34>:    mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 0x28 <main+40>
   0x0000000000000028 <+40>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
   0x000000000000002b <+43>:    je     0x40 <main+64>
   0x000000000000002d <+45>:    lea    0x0(%rip),%rsi        # 0x34 <main+52>
   0x0000000000000034 <+52>:    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 0x3b <main+59>
   0x000000000000003b <+59>:    callq  0x40 <main+64>
   0x0000000000000040 <+64>:    mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 0x46 <main+70>
   0x0000000000000046 <+70>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
```

So the repeating code is the "lea" and "callq". Based on the way I'm reading it, it's just pointing to the next line down. For example, the first lea ends with #0xb <main+11> which is the line right below it, and that one points to the line below it, and so on. Can anyone help with what I'm looking at?

There's at least a hundred extra lines in the project, so I'm not looking for a free A, I just need help understanding.

Edit: I am working with a .o file without access to the original .cpp file and the task is to use GDB and Bless to help me read the Assembly output and reassemble it into a .cpp file that works the same as the original code.

Comment: To me it looks like "the binary" that you are disassembling is not linked by linker into executable yet and so the disassembler misrepresents its contents.

Comment: are you trying to make a disassembler?  and you understand that for x86, being variable instruction length, you have to do this in execution order, you cannot just linearly disassemble through loadable bytes (even gnu tools struggle with x86).

Comment: @old_timer: It looks like they're trying to manually reverse engineer from a binary back to C++, using a disassembler.  In non-obfuscated code, static disassembly Just Works.  Given that GDB was even able to find function symbols like `main`, and that the disassembly looks totally normal for a `.o` (where a linker hasn't filled in the relocations for call targets and static data), that doesn't look like anything to worry about in this case.

Comment: yeah, well you can never get back to C++ in a natural looking program form, you can certainly have C++ that looks like assembly.   binutils relies heavily and is only (remotely) successful when there are sufficient labels/debug data in the binary but if you strip those then binutils fails miserably to disassemble, much less use that disassembly to do anything somewhat useful.  If this was compiled then linear disassembly will struggle at best.  If the code was hand written assembly for the purposes of education then you can disassemble linearly.

Comment: this really needs to have a complete example from the source code, to the binary, to the disassembly, and on as needed.  this fragment without more is not very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So the repeating code is the "lea" and "callq".

The addresses suggest that you are disassembling `.o` file, not an executable (you should *always* show the command you used when asking about its output).

Try `objdump -dr foo.o` instead -- the picture should become much clearer.

P.S. GDB isn't really the right tool for looking at `.o` files anyway.

**Update:**

> I tried the `objdump -dr Project1.o` and got pretty much the same output

Look closer: it's *not* the same output. `objdump` will display relocations, which show where he `CALL` will actually go to.

You should also be able to link `Project1.o` into an executable (something like `gcc Project1.o -o Project1`), and run `gdb Project1` and then `disas main`. You will see that *that* disassembly makes more sense, and also matches the output of `objdump`.

Comment: So GDB is part of the class. We have access to GDB and Bless to assist us.

I tried the objdump -dr Project1.o and got pretty much the same output. 

Also, thank you for the help with clarifying my question. I am disassembling a .o file, without access to the .cpp file it came from. My task is to read the assembly and reassemble it in a .cpp.

Comment: @Troutt025: "pretty much the same output" *except for meaningful comments at the right with the symbol name of the actual target address*.  That's the entire point, and something I don't think GDB can give you.  After a linker has created an executable out of your `.o`, the `call rel32` instructions won't actually be jumping to the instruction right after them, they'll be jumping to `printf` or whatever.  Similarly the `mov` loads/stores aren't accessing the machine code of this function, they'll be accessing globals in `.data` or `.bss`  (or `.rodata`).

Comment: @Troutt025 I've updated the answer with some additional clues.

Comment: @Employed Russian: So I went back to look again at the objdump command and you're right, I did miss the relocations. It does give a better view of things. For instance, line 0x17 now shows `callq  1c <main+0x1c> 18: R_X86_64_PC32 _Z25CheckUserPermissionAccessv-0x4` which I believe is calling the function "CheckUserPermissionAccess". When I tried the gcc command I just get a bunch of errors for undefined references and it exits. But if it matches the output of objdump then it's no big deal. Thank you for your help! I think I may be able to get it working with this.